# How to get raw HTTP response pages on Firefox/Internet explorer instead of user friendly message?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, http

Is it possible to configure firefox and IE9 to display the raw HTTP error pages sent from a server instead of the user friendly one they now use (pic below)

[image]

This would save me having to go to my server logs all the time for the specific codes etc.

I preferred the olden' days of doing it (pic below)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Firefox use [LiveHttp headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) pluggin to view the Http Headers responses from server. You will see the Status Code like HTTP/1.1 404 FILE NOT FOUND in there.

It will look like this:
[image]

I don't think there is a pluggin for IE but you could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyse the web Traffic - it will show you in details all packets including Headers.

Here is how Fiddler looks:
[image]

To summarize: Browsers are created to **interpret the Hyper Text** not display all the content of the packets - this is the job for sniffers/debuggers. You can use mentioned above tools in Windows or **tcpdump** on Linux. As a side note - you could see Headers in **Wireshark** on Windows as well but this is overkill since you will see more then the network layer you need. You need only Application Layer and you would see That plus Network and Data Link layer in there as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Mozilla Firefox, the status codes are visible (eventually after refresh) in the Network monitor (Ctrl+Shift+E) of the builtin Developer tools (Ctrl+Shft+I).

[image: FF screenshot]